# Dynamically generating where statements during runtime

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using Sqlalchemy to automate SQL queries analyzing A/B tests we run.

Here's an example query:

```
    uniques_by_day = select([
                        first_seen_byos.c.unique_id,
                        func.date_trunc('day', a_unique_users.c.ds).label('current_day'),
                        func.date_trunc('day', first_seen_byos.c.ds).label('cohort_join_day')
                        ]).\
                    select_from(joined_table).\
                    where(
                        and_(
                            a_unique_users.c.os_type == 'iphone_native_app',
                            first_seen_byos.c.ds >= '2017-01-01'
                            )
                        )
```

What's going to change between queries is the clauses for the where / and_ statement. How do I go about writing a general statement that's able to consume a dynamic set of where clauses? I'm anticipating that these clauses will always be a series of AND clauses.

Comment: does `where( 1=1 and_(...))` help?

Comment: Not sure how I would use that in this context

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this when I need to dynamically build a query:

```
query = session.query(MyTable)
if case_1:
    query = query.filter(MyTable.column_1 == 'foo')
if case_2:
    query = query.filter(MyTable.column_2 == 'bar')
query_results = query.all()
```

This is using the declarative base syntax but I think it gets idea across.